# How to find matrix $\mathbf{R}$ is a function of matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ as the following equation:

Tags: matrices

$\mathbf{R}^T\otimes\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{A}^T\otimes\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}^T\otimes\mathbf{B}$

Where $\otimes$ is Kronecker Products. $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are given matrices and $\mathbf{R}$ is unknown.
Any suggestion are welcome.
Thanks,
Dinh

Comment: Have you tried writing $A^T \otimes A$, $B^T \otimes B$, $R^T \otimes R$ in matrix form?

Comment: Hi Weaam !. Here $\mathbf{R}$ is unkown and $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are known before.  I want to solve such equation to get $\mathbf{R}$ as a solution.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. I was wondering what have you tried so far? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Writing down the tensor products:

$$A^T \otimes A + B^T \otimes B = \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} A & a_{21} A & \dots & a_{n1}A\\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots\\
a_{1n} A & a_{2n} A & \dots & a_{nn}A
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}b_{11} B & b_{21} B & \dots & b_{n1}B\\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots\\
b_{1n} B & b_{2n} B & \dots & b_{nn}B
\end{pmatrix}$$

Similarly for $R$.  Then, for each $i,j \leq n$, we have $$r_{ij}R = a_{ij}A + b_{ij}B$$

But they should agree at each element as well, therefore

$$r_{ij}r_{mn} = a_{ij}a_{rm} + b_{ij}b_{rm} \qquad\qquad \forall i, j, r, m\leq n $$

You can construct $R$ (assuming it is consistent) by restricting the equation to $rm$ = $ij$, so that $R = (r_{ij})$ has elements

$$r_{ij} = \sqrt{a_{ij}^2 + b_{ij}^2}$$ from $A$ and $B$.

To check for consistency, we see that $$r_{ij}r_{rm} = \sqrt{a_{ij}^2 + b_{ij}^2}\sqrt{a_{rm}^2 + b_{rm}^2} = a_{ij}a_{rm} + b_{ij}b_{rm}$$

Squaring we obtain a relation that $A$ and $B$ must satisfy? Can you determine it?

Computationally, we ought to construct $R^T \otimes R$ and see if it matches $A^T \otimes A + B^T \otimes B$.

---

**For a counterexample** (of which I'm sure there will be plenty)

Take $A = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 3\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix} \implies A^T \otimes A = \begin{pmatrix}2A & 0\\ 3A&A\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}4 & 6 & 0 & 0\\ 0& 2 & 0 & 0\\ 6 & 9 & 2 & 3\\0 & 3 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

$B = \begin{pmatrix}3 & 1\\ 1&2\end{pmatrix} \implies B^T \otimes B= \begin{pmatrix}3B & B\\ B&2B\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}9 & 3 & 3 & 1\\ 3& 6 & 1 & 2\\ 3 & 1 & 6 & 2\\1 & 2 & 2 & 4\end{pmatrix}$

Then $$A^T \otimes A + B^T \otimes B = \begin{pmatrix}13 & 9 & 3 & 1\\ 3& 8 & 1 & 2\\ 9 & 10 & 8 & 5\\1 & 5 & 2 & 5\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus we are seeking $R$ by solving the set of equation. But we note immediately that if $R^T \otimes R = A^T \otimes A + B^T \otimes B$, then $$r_{12}r_{21} = 10 \neq r_{21}r_{12} = 1$$ thus there can't be such $R$.

---

**For a trivial example of such $R$**

Take $A, B = I_n$. Then $R = \sqrt{2}I_n$ satisfies $R^T \otimes R = 2 I_n\otimes I_n = A^T \otimes A + B^T \otimes B$.

Comment: Thanks Weaam for your answer but it is still difficult to derive a closed-form solution of R. I will try and give a feedback to you later.

Comment: You have assumed that $A$, $B$ and $R$ are the same sizes here, right? It could be that $A$ is $m \times n$, $B$ is $n \times m$ and $r$ , could it not?

Comment: @Calle Yes, the OP didn't specify the size of the given $A, B$ so I assumed, for simplicity's sake, they were square. In hope to show that existence of such $R$ puts a constraint on $A, B$ themselves.